# Getting valiues from dictionary key using python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, traversal

I am building method to search/traverse a dictionary, and there are couple thing i cant seem to figure out.

If i have a dictionary "book"

if I use:
    `for key,value in book.iteritems(): print (key,value)`

I will get a list of keys and values.

If i wanted to print the first key or the first key + value without knowing the key, how would i do it?

If i wanted to print each subkey separately of the book and its value without knowing anything about the book, how would i do it?

Example of the first key in my book:

`(u'book', {u'cover_type': u'hard_cover', u'author_id': 10, u'page_type': u'white', u'page_material_name': u'paper', u'series_inifial_version': 0, u'printer_version': u'3.5', u'series_name': u'dragon_blade', u'id': u'158774', u'series_final_version': 2})`

The output that i would like to achieve:

`cover_type hard_cover`

`author_id 10`

etc...

If i knew the the subkey `cover_type`, how would i print its value?

Comment: `first key or the first key + value` - There is no order in the dictionary, so there is no "first". You might want to store data in `OrderedDict`

Comment: when i mention first key + value, i dont mean to print them in a specified order. For example if there were 5 keys at what ever random order they are, i would like to print what ever is the first key, value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thefourtheye has mentioned in the comment, there's no order on dictionaries, but if you don't care about order, just print the first key/value that appears, you could do:

```
for key,value in book.iteritems(): 
    print(key,value)
    break
```

Comment: what i meant is that lets say there are 5 keys in dictionary, is there a way to print only key 0 or key 1 or key 2, etc...? Instead of listing keys and then print them using book[key]

Comment: You could do: `book.keys()[1]` for keys or `book.values()[1]` for values.

On python 3 you have to cast things to list `list(book.keys())[1]` or `list(book.values())[1]`

Comment: i would like to stay away from lists. 

How about my last question, if i wanted to print all sub keys and its values from a dictionary.

Comment: The tupple you represent there is your key, rigth? So, key[0] is u'book' and key[1] is your dict. Just use: `for k, v in key[1].items(): print(k, v)`. Just curious: what are you really trying to do?